# How to program contigencies that are executed with varying frequency?

Tags: java, random

Say I have 3 cases that I want them to be executed, but not always.

E.g.

```
Case 1 --> happens always
Case 2 --> happens 20% of times
Case 3 --> happens 60% of times
```

How can I go about to program this? Here's what I thought so far:

```
x = nextInt(100);
execute case 1
if( x <= 20 ){
 execute case 2
}
if ( x <= 60 ){
 execute case 3
}
```

Is there a different approach to this problem? Maybe some function that I'm unaware of? The java random documentation doesn't seem to have something for this.

Comment: Looks good to me, but you should take into consideration if case2 and case3 are linked, because with your solution, case3 will always occur when case2 occurs, don't know if that is intended, otherwise you should generate a new random for each check separately

Answer (score 5):

You can use the library math of apache.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/EnumeratedDistribution.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe is a little overkill

```
List<Pair<Boolean,Double>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<Boolean,Double>>();
list.add(new ImmutablePair(true, 0.2));
list.add(new ImmutablePair(false, 0.8));

EnumeratedDistribution e = new EnumeratedDistribution(list);   

//execute case 1

if (e.sample()) {
  //execute case 2
} 
...
```

But if your logic change you can have thing like this:

```
List<Pair<String,Double>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Double>>();
list.add(new ImmutablePair("name_1", 0.2));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("name_2", 0.4));
list.add(new ImmutablePair("name_3", 0.4));
EnumeratedDistribution e = new EnumeratedDistribution(list);    

switch(e.sample()) {
  case "name_1" :
    ...
  break;
  case "name_2" :
    ...
  break;
  case "name_3" :
    ...
  break;
}
```

Where only one case is executed and each case has a different probability of being executed. It is very flexible.